# How can I get a list of named databases in an lmdb env?

Tags: lmdb

How does one get a list of the named databases that are part of an env ? From reading some python binding docs [(named database implementation)](https://lmdb.readthedocs.io/en/release/#lmdb.Environment.open_db), I understand the names are stored in the main (unnamed?) db, but I'm not seeing them when browsing with a cursor.

Answer (score 9):

All the named databases are stored in unnamed database as keys. Get all the keys then you will get list of named databases.
For this open dbi without any database name i.e pass null for named databse argument and read all the keys.

You can find it in the following documentation link:
[lmdb documentation](http://104.237.133.194/doc/group__mdb.html#gac08cad5b096925642ca359a6d6f0562a)